# Highlight image on object:over in fabric js

Tags: html5-canvas, photos, fabricjs

I am making photo collage application for which I need better object selection method. The current or default selecting technique is little bit confused when there are lot's of objects. User are confused on which object is selected. So I want to highlight over the object before selecting it so that use know prior which object is going to be selected.

I have looked at [hovering](http://fabricjs.com/hovering/) which is what I want but it is only for shapes and don't work for images. How to apply this to images, text and cliparts.

Here is the code :

```
                canvas.on('object:over', function(e) {
                    //I want to draw border only (not corner) on mouseover and non-selected object
                });

                canvas.on('object:out', function(e) {
                    //I want to remove the border on mouseout on non-selected object                  
                });
```

The border and corner is only applicable for selected objects but I want to enable border for non-selected object on mouse hovering.

Here is my app : [Edit Photos For Free](http://editphotosforfree.com)

Comment: hovering should work for any object, including images

Comment: I mean the demo example of hovering only works for shapes and not for images because image is opaque in which color change on hover cannot be seen. So I want to apply border around opaque object when hovering. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

For now I think the solution for this is -

```
canvas.on('mouseover', function(e) {
                    //I want to draw border only (not corner) on mouseover and non-selected object
                });
canvas.on('mouseout', function(e) {
                    //I want to remove the border on mouseout on non-selected object                  
                });
```